# Did any other latinamerican country win the Davis cup besides Argentina?

Tags: tennis, davis-cup

When I hear about Davis cup champions I always hear about United States, Australia, England, Spain, etc. but never heard of a latinamerican country wining it. Is Argentina the first latinamerican country to win the Copa Davis?

Comment: There is [List of Davis Cup champions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Davis_Cup_champions) on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at [List of Davis Cup champions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Davis_Cup_champions#Performance_by_team) on Wikipedia you can see that:

- In [2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Davis_Cup), [Argentina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argentina_Davis_Cup_team) became the first country from Latin America to win Davis Cup. (Before that Argentina ended up as runner-up four times.)
- [Mexico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexico_Davis_Cup_team) was runner-up in [1962](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1962_Davis_Cup).
- [Chile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chile_Davis_Cup_team) was runner-up in [1976](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1976_Davis_Cup)